# How to convert if to switch-case in c

Tags: c, switch-statement

```
if(a > b)
{printf("%d is greater than %d", a, b);}
else if( a < b )
{printf("%d is greater than %d", b, a);}
else
{printf("%d is equal to %d", a, b);}
```

How do I convert an if statement to a switch-case in C?
I'm trying, but i don't know the answer to this problem

Comment: Why do you want to do that? You can’t (…). `switch` statements can only test equality.

Comment: It's a non-problem. Don't convert anything, it's absolutely fine as it is (except it's not indented properly).

Comment: You could use a really weird construction like `switch((a>b) + 10*(a<b))` and then check for values 0, 1, 10. But... DON'T DO THIS!

Comment: it's not entirely impossible - you could have a `case` statement for every possible integer value and do `switch(a-b)`...but adding several million lines of code that can be done with a couple seems like a huge step backwards

Comment: A switch statement is intended to select among multiple cases depending on the value of a *single* variable.  You don't have that case.  You're looking at the relationship between *two* variables.  You would need to convert that relationship into a single value in order to use a switch statement, but it wouldn't save you anything to do so.

Comment: @Gerhardh great idea ^^

Comment: @bruno ^^ I hope no one will ever use such crazy BS in real life.

Comment: @Gerhardh all is possible, all. How many times I see `if(...) a =  true; else a =  false;` ...

Comment: @bruno, true. One of my favorites: `sprintf(buf,"%s","");` to initialize an empty string. :)

Comment: @Gerhardh few days ago I see `strcat(s, "");` and the OP explaining that adds a null char if not present (was really _strcat_, not _strcpy_) ^^

Answer (score 7):

`switch` statements are used to test an input expression against a finite set of possible values.

You're trying to compare two variables. This is not a use case for `switch`.

Your `if` / `else if` chain is fine.

Comment: Up-voted. Kudos for not endorsing heck like `(a < b) - (a > b)` inside `expression` part of `switch`.

Answer (score 5):

```
switch ((a < b) - (a > b)) {
case -1:
    printf("%d is greater than %d", a, b);
    break;
case 1:
    printf("%d is greater than %d", b, a);
    break;
default:
    printf("%d is equal to %d", a, b);
}
```

Comment: But why the heck? :)

Comment: `true` is `1` and `false` is `0`

Comment: Nice solution. If I will see such a thing in a code review, someone is up for a keyboard ban. ;)

Comment: @Gerhardh about a ban someone downvoted my answer, probably needing glasses to read 'joke', or not liking the jokes ? ^^

Comment: @Gerhardh Hope you will never encounter anything like `while (*dst++ = *src++);` during code reviews.

Comment: @bruno, your `switch` expression is clumsy, that could be the reason?

Comment: @machine_1 In my (humble?) opinion, the `<=>` operator of C++ somewhat legitimises this.

Comment: @Bathsheba of course the expression is, else no joke

Comment: @MikhailVladimirov This classic one line version of `strcpy` is much more straight forward.

Answer (score 2):

**joke** :

```
switch ((a > b) ? 1 : ((a == b) ? 0 : -1)) {
case 1:
  printf("%d is greater than %d", a, b);
  break;
case 0:
  printf("%d is equal to %d", a, b);
  break;
default:
  printf("%d is greater than %d", b, a);
}
```

Comment: be careful suggesting code like this: you never know who is going to read and learn from this. :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh ^^

Answer (score 1):

You're stumbling on a *three way comparison* here.

You could write `switch ((a < b) - (a > b)) {` with -1, 0 and +1 as the case labels for `a < b`, `a == b`, and `a > b` respectively. Note that you need the parentheses since binary `-` has a higher precedence than `<` or `>`.

In C++ that expression has been encapsulated in the *three way comparison operator* `<=>` and you could write, simply

```
switch (a <=> b){
```

with the case labels as before. As far as I know there is no proposal to include that operator in C.